# Changing table row height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-selectors

I am trying to change the row height of a table belonging to a particular class to 0.

Currently I am doing  this:

```
$("#table_rolecart tbody").append('<tr class='hide'><td>Start Date: <input type="text" value="" id="ar_startdate"></td><td>End Date: <input type="text" value="" id="ar_enddate"></td></tr>');
$('.hide').height = "0"
```

It's still not zero, how do I set the height to 0 or set display style to none for those `<tr>`s?

Comment: How about just using CSS with `.hide { display: none; }`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `css` function:

```
$('.hide').css('height', '0');
```

If you want to remove them from sight, you can also set `display: none`:

```
$('.hide').css('display', 'none');
```

You can also remove them entirely:

```
$('.hide').remove();
```

If you don't need to hide them dynamically, however, you should just be using CSS:

```
.hide {
    height: 0;
    /* or display: none */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Height is a css property, so you can set it with the css function

```
$('.hide').css("height", "0");
```

Note that you can also hide it with

```
$('.hide').css("display", "none");
```

Answer (score 1):

Either of these techniques will set a row's height to 0:

```
$(".hide").height(0);
$(".hide").css("height", 0);
```

But tables are tricky and setting the height to 0 won't cause a row to hide.  The easiest way to hide the row is to use either of these techniques:

```
$(".hide").hide();
$(".hide").css("display", "none");
```

But, if you want to hide the row using height (for whatever reason), also set the `line-height` to 0. Then, on the child cells, set the `padding` to 0 (and possibly also the `border`) and set `overflow` to `hidden`.

```
$(".hide").css({
    height: 0,
    lineHeight: 0
});
$(".hide > *").css({
    padding: 0,
    overflow: "hidden"
});
```

But, in your case, even this won't work, because the input controls still display.  You'd have to wrap the cell contents in a container such as a div and hide that.

Comment: just have one last thing to do, How do I make the height 0 only for previous 2 rows. not the current row

Comment: `$(".hide").prev().prev().andSelf().hide()` should do it.  Or `$(".hide").prev().hide().prev().hide()`

Comment: I found that setting vertical-align:middle to all the TD's in the row ($(this).find("td").css("vertical-align","middle");) allowed the row to be 0 height when combined with the technique above.  Not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `$('.hide').height(0);`