# dynamically increase row size of HTML table in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to JavaScript and just learning the basics of it. I am doing a sample program and crated a javascript program to show some data in a html page inside div. but it is not dynamic. I have some values like name, addess, age and status of few staff and while log in with a user name showing the above details in html page. this is a simple program.

What i want to do is, i want to dynamically increase the size of the div or table where i can display details of use like address, age, status etc.. if some user has more details then i want to add that in the html page. how can i do it ?? 
in home.jsp i have the following code.

```
<table>
    <div id="name1" width:400px;"></div>
    <div id="address1" width:400px;"></div>
    <div id="age1" width:400px;"></div>
    <div id="status1" width:400px;"></div>
</table>
```

this is the function i use in home.js

```
function(json)
{   
    var content= $('#name1').replaceWith('<tr><td> Name: ' + json.name + '<tr><td>');
    var content= $('#address1').replaceWith('<tr><td> Name: ' + json.address + '<tr><td>');
    var content= $('#age1').replaceWith('<tr><td> Name: ' + json.age + '<tr><td>');
    var content= $('#status1').replaceWith('<tr><td> Name: ' + json.status + '<tr><td>');
}
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid, please see [permitted content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table) for `table`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing table row height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584556/changing-table-row-height)

Comment: this is my json.function hello()
{ 
   
 //alert("entered in hello function");
 var username = document.getElementById('uname').value;
 var password = document.getElementById('pswd').value;
 //alert("the password is:"+password);
 $.ajaxSetup ({  
    cache: false  
    
     }); 

 
 $.getJSON(
    'SampleWebProject/sample.action'
    ,
     { 
     name:username,
        password:password
        
       
     //dataSource  : dataSource 
     },

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to do a loop and in that

You have to use `append()` ex.

`$( "#your_div_id" ).append( "<tr><td> your_label: ' + json.your_values + '<tr><td>'" );`

[Reference Link](https://api.jquery.com/append/)

Comment: i used append but that time i had another problem.. after running once. that user details will be on html page. and then again when i run next time i cannot delete the old content and display new user details in the page. the new user details in showing with the old user details. i dont know how to refresh page automatically by clicking the button and delete the old content from html page.

Comment: add `$( "#your_div_id" ).html('')` before `append()` line

Comment: thank you this works .and this is how i wanted to empty the html while clicking the button and show new data. thanks man,

Comment: With your original HTML, all these elements are appened _outside_ of the table.

Answer (score 1):

You must read JQuery api Document.

url : http://api.jquery.com/append/

maybe you used `.append()`, `.toAppend()`, `.prepand()`, `.after()` etc..

code example(.after())

```
$('#table' tr:last).after('<tr><th width="10%">' + //your code here // + '</th></tr>');
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to change you `HTML` like,

```
<table>
    <tr id="name1"></tr>
    <tr id="address1"></tr>
    <tr id="age1"></tr>
    <tr id="status1"></tr>
</table>
```

And if your `json` is valid then you can use [append()](http://api.jquery.com/append) like,

```
$('#name1').append('<td> Name: ' + json.name + '</td>');
$('#address1').append('<td> Address: ' + json.address + '</td>');
$('#age1').append('<td> Age: ' + json.age + '</td>');
$('#status1').append('<td> Status: ' + json.status + '</td>');
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/2bcDV/)**

Comment: <table>
    <tr id="name1"></tr>
    <tr id="address1"></tr>
    <tr id="age1"></tr>
    <tr id="status1"></tr>
</table>   In this code we are hard coring the <tr id> names.. like id="name1" etc.. but can i dynamically arrange those and expand tr with new values coming.. if a user has phone number and i want to add that to <tr phone="phone1"> or some way i can dynamicaaly add new tr field to the html page?